# ZXing: listVideoInputDevices method returns redundant entries

Tags: javascript, zxing, zxing-js

I'm using the **zxing** api to scan barcodes with my mobile phone. The **listVideoInputDevices** method from **BrowserMultiFormatReader** lists all available cameras from the device. But why is the rear camera listed **three times** and the front camera once on my A53 smartphone? Why does the method return **redundant entries**?